# Dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on my machine with 1 HDD but it's starting to get very slow.

So I decided to buy some new stuff (mobo, CPU, memory, SSD and 2 HDD). Now I would like to make it a dual boot with a new install (12.10) on the SSD and the old installation on my old HDD. In a few months, I will pull out the old HDD and put it in a new box for my kids. But until then it should be able to boot into the old version.

What's the best way to do this? I have tried something similair a few years back but that gave me a lot problems. Each update/upgrade gave problems with the boot loader and I had to change things manually after which it start working again. I'm trying to prevent that this time.

My own thought would be to remove my old drive, put in the SSD, install Ubuntu from CD. After the installation is completed, I plug in my old HDD and run update-grub.

Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Typically, booting an OS on another architecture/different hardware setup is not recommended.

Once you install your OS on your SSD and plug in your HDD, grubupdate should add your other drive as a boot option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, booting an OS on another architecture/different hardware setup is not recommended. Once you install your OS on your SSD and plug in your HDD, **grubupdate** should add your other drive as a boot option.